# setState after async action in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Which lifecycle method I should use to set the existing value in a form? I can't do `<input value={this.props.title} />` because I want to make input as a controlled component.

I can do a promise then after the async method but will this be anti pattern?

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchItem(this.itemId)
  .then(v=>{this.setState({title: v.title})})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use componentWillReceiveProps() method to set your props value to state.

Something like this.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
 // store your props value to state here
if(nextProps.formData !== undefined){
  this.setState({ formData: nextProps.formData });
  }

}
```

To update that state value on input change method

```
handleChange = (name, value) => {
  // update state here
  this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }
```

Comment: nextProps.formData is undefined at first.

Comment: you can add some validation, like (nextProps.formData !== undefined)